# How to use reflection to get all the variables in an object?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

I'm currently using this code to get all the variables in an object and place the data in a Dictionary (the key is a variable name, the value is the variable's contents).

```
foreach (var property in PropertiesOfType<string>(propertiesJSON))
{
    dictionary.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
}
```

In this code, *propertiesJSON* is the object I need. Here's the PropertiesOfType method:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object obj)
{
    return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
           where p.PropertyType == typeof(T)
           select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
}
```

When I test my Dictionary for any data, there are no values (I used Visual Studio's debugging stuff to check, and my program also printed out all the data inside the Dictionary - which is of course, not there). Please tell me the mistake I'm doing here (I'm still learning to code, I'm 15 at the time of posting this).

EDIT: This is how propertiesJSON looks like

```
var propertiesJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.PropertiesJSON>(content);
```

Here is the class itself:

```
class PropertiesJSON
{
    public string botToken;
    public bool girl;
    public int age;
    public string[] hi;
    public string test;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `propertiesJSON`? Can you post an example?

Comment: Try printing `propertiesJSON.GetType()`. And check if that type actually has any string properties.

Comment: @Konamiman It's a normal class with basic variables which I use as a model for serializing and deserializing JSON. I added the code

Comment: @Sweeper It just gives the location of my class

Comment: show us the JSON please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are not properties!

These:

```
public string botToken;
public bool girl;
public int age;
public string[] hi;
public string test;
```

are all fields. If they were properties, they would have looked like this:

```
public string botToken { get; }
public bool girl  { get; }
public int age  { get; }
public string[] hi  { get; }
public string test  { get; }
```

To get the fields, use `GetFields` instead of `GetProperties`.

```
return from p in obj.GetType().GetFields()
       where p.FieldType == typeof(T)
       select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
```

I suggest that you change the fields to all properties.

Comment: additionally, traditionally JsonNET will not de/serialize fields.  I have no idea if that is now an option or not.

Comment: @SamAxe ikr. I was kind of surprised as well.

Comment: Wow this is what happens when you self learn coding, you don't get all the tiny details. And btw, there's a mistake in your last code snippet. Replace _PropertyType_ with _FieldType_